# Find the last occurrence of the end of a word

Tags: php, regex, position

I have a string and I'm trying to find the last occurrence of an end of a word. E.G.:

> This is a test string and I need to find the last occurrence of a word. This sentence will be cut sho
>
> ```
>                                                                         ^
>
>                 I want to find the position of the space between cut and short
> ```

I've tried using the end of word character symbol (`\b`) but on it's own it doesn't match anything. I also tried `/[\w\d]\b/g` but that matches the "t" of cut and the "o" of sho, not what I need.

Comment: Do you want to trim it off?

Comment: @nhahtdh yes, I have a string of x length and I'm cutting it down to 300 characters, that sometimes leaves me with half a word at the end that I need to trim off.

Comment: Just use [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php)?

Comment: Just wondering, how do you know the last word is a half-word? Are you using a dictionary?

Comment: @HamZa `strrpos()` doesn't work with regular expressions.

Comment: @kums I don't, I'm just assuming it is for safety. In theory I could just check character 301 in the original string to see if that's an end of word character, but it's overkill for what I need.

Comment: @Styphon I misunderstood the question. My bad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find last space (or any non-word character) just before last word use:

```
\W(?=\w+\W*$)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hT9rJ3/1)

Answer (score 1):

The regex

```
\s(?=\w+$)
```

would match the last space in the string